# Commands in .bash_profile do not run

Tags: bash, monterey

I have this issue with `bash` on a MacBook Pro (chip M1, OS: 12.5.1). It's been there since day 1.

- I set `bash` as the default shell in Terminal>Preferences>General [image]

- I create and modify a new `.bash_profile` file in my `~` folder using `vi` so I can exclude line-ending issues, formatting issues due to the editor, and such
- Most of the commands I write in the `.bash_profile` file do not work. For example, `echo` seems to work; `source` returns "No such file or directory" **even when the file actually exists and the path is correct**; `ls` and many others give "Command not found". **All those commands run in the terminal with no problems at all**
- the `PATH` variable seems okay. `export` doesn't return an error message. Without appending new paths in `.bash_profile`, I have `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`, which is what I expect looking into `/etc/paths.d/`
- for example, the line `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"` to `.bash_profile` doesn't produce any error when sourcing the file; the line `source "/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/root_v6.26.06/bin/thisroot.sh"` (file, path verified) gives `No such file or directory`
- the `/etc/paths` file is still untouched:

  `/usr/local/bin`
  `/usr/bin`
  `/bin`
  `/usr/sbin`
  `/sbin`
- probably part of the same problem, the terminal overwrites the lines that are longer than the window length
- among the attempts to solve the problem, I updated `bash` to a more recent version, 5.1.0; `bash --version` responds accordingly. Same errors.
- the issue was there with previous OS versions as well. Updating didn't help

Hopefully, someone who ran into the same issues can share some good hints. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It looks like there's a problem with `PATH`: move the `export PATH` line to the top of `.bashrc`, otherwise `bash` won't know where to search for commands. As for the "No such file or directory" error when running `source`, **either** escape spaces with backslash notation (`source /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/root_v6.26.06/bin/thisroot.sh`), **or** with double quotes (`source "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/root_v6.26.06/bin/thisroot.sh"`), but don't use both.

Comment: If the comment from @jaume doesn't solve your problem, please add your `.bashrc` to the question.

Comment: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH` should not be needed, these directories are already in PATH (based on the content in `/etc/paths`). `/etc/paths` is static, not sure why you mention this in the question at all.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your replies! 

- Having either quotes or backslashes in the source lines actually solves the problem. Nice spot @jaume!
- Moving the `PATH` definition line to the top didn't change things
- All other commands in the file are now correctly executed
- Lines are no longer overwritten
- No differences between .bash_profile and .bashrc
- for a correctly working system, the `export PATH` line is not needed - I agree with @nohillside. Here, it could have helped to understand
- Root is still not correctly sourced, but I think this doesn't belong here

Comment: With this configuration, I would have expected that .bash_profile does not get sourced at all, when you open a new terminal tab. This file is only processed for interactive **login** shells. Could it be that you explicitly source it from somewhere (for instance, from .bahshrc)?

Comment: @user1934428 on macOS, each new Terminal tab runs a login shell.

Comment: @nohillside : In this case, no. Of course if you use the default, you get your default login shell. But the OP selected the alternative to open a shell of his choice, by providing the **complete command** to start up the shell, and Terminal has no way to figure out what options to add in order to make it a login shell. For instance, I use `zsh` for my Terminal, and I had to specify explicitly `/bin/zsh -l` to get a login shell.

Comment: @user1934428 Ah right, didn‘t look at the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your replies! I think the problem is now **solved**

- Having either quotes or backslashes in the source lines actually solves the problem. Nice spot @jaume!
- Moving the `PATH` definition line to the top didn't change things
- All other commands in the file are now correctly executed
- Lines are no longer overwritten
- No differences between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`
- For a correctly working system, the `export PATH` line is not needed - I agree with @nohillside. Here, it could have helped to understand
- Root is still not correctly sourced, but I think this doesn't belong here

Comment: Not sure I understand the last point.

Comment: Root is the name of a data analysis tool, https://root.cern/. I am having  troubles with the installation

Comment: Glad you have resolved it. I'm curious, what changes have you made so that commands are now executed?

Comment: It only was having the backslash inside the quotes. I understand that having a single syntax error invalidates the whole file, no matter the position of the mistaken line...

Comment: The installation is also now solved. The residual issue was `root-config: command not found`, with the file present in the correct directory. Workaround: 
`cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/root_v6.26.06/bin/;`
`source thisroot.sh;`
`cd` in `.bash_profile`